# HTML CSS: How to prevent image distortion with responsiveness?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm creating a site on which users are able to post various ads. Every ad should have a title, description, image and etc. The most important thing is the image, the image represents all the ads in the UI. For now, I'm using a grid system, but I didn't really paid attention to the grid sizes for phones, tablets and etc. which is really important.

[image]

These are the original sizes of the photos, as you can see they are pretty different, is there any better way to handle the responsiveness and prevent distortion?

[image]

This is how React renders ads:

```
<AdContainer>
      {AdsList.map((ad: AdI) => (
        <AdWrapper>
          <AdPhotoWrapper>
            <AdPhoto src={ad.description}></AdPhoto>
          </AdPhotoWrapper>
          <AdInformation>
            <AdTitle>{ad.title}</AdTitle>
            <AdLocationWrapper>
              <AdLocation>
                <AdCountry>{ad.country} </AdCountry>
                <AdCity>{ad.city}</AdCity>
              </AdLocation>
            </AdLocationWrapper>
            <AdPriceWrapper>
              <AdPrice>
                <AdPriceCurrency>{ad.currency}</AdPriceCurrency>
                <AdPriceSum>{ad.price}</AdPriceSum>
              </AdPrice>
            </AdPriceWrapper>
          </AdInformation>
        </AdWrapper>
      ))}
</AdContainer>
```

Styles:

```
const AdContainer = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 0.2fr 0.2fr 0.2fr 0.2fr 0.2fr 0.2fr 0.2fr;
  padding: 1rem 2rem 0 2rem;
`;

const AdPhotoWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%; // To avoid the image distortion
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0.6rem;
`;

const AdPhoto = styled.img`
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%; // To avoid the image distortion
`;

const AdTitle = styled.h3`
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: ${colors.whitePrimary};
`;
const AdLocationWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -0.25rem;
`;
const AdLocation = styled.p`
  margin: 0;
  color: ${colors.grayThird};
`;
const AdCountry = styled.span``;
const AdCity = styled.span``;
const AdInformation = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const AdPriceWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  margin-top: -0.4rem;
`;
const AdPrice = styled.h2`
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  color: ${colors.whitePrimary};
`;
const AdPriceCurrency = styled.span`
  padding-right: 0.3rem;
`;
const AdPriceSum = styled.span``;
```

Comment: use `aspect-ratio` and `object-fit` css properties

Comment: So I shouldn't play around with height and width?

Comment: not required. grid can handle that for you. just set width to 100% and object fit to cover. maybe put image inside a div and add overflow: hidden to that div so image is behind the div container

Comment: @boxdox https://gyazo.com/43dc1cae86d939cfefe609720cdd7450 Why does it not make any difference after applying `object-fit`?

Comment: because you've given `height: 100%` to it. try removing it

Comment: Hmm, I tried applying height to `AdPhotoWrapper`, object-fit to `AdPhotoWrapper`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236020/discussion-between-user9745220-and-boxdox).

Comment: As the users are supplying the images so you have no idea which bit of the image can be cropped or not you may prefer to use object-fit: contain which will ensure all their image can be seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure the user's image can all be seen OK try this:

```
const AdPhoto = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
`;
```

(Note: don't try aspect-ratio just yet as it's only just coming into being supported on Safari so a lot of users still won't be able to use it).